# How to install this intel driver on windows 10?

Tags: windows, drivers, 64-bit

I have hp 630 and 2 windows (windows 10 and 7) both are 64bit i have i3 370M with integreted Intel Hd graphic card ( no numbers or smth the name is : intel hd graphic)

i got the driver from intel  website which is this 
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/22521/Intel-Graphics-Media-Accelerator-Driver-Windows-7-64-Windows-Vista-64-exe-?product=97497
it installed normally on windows 7 without any problem but in windows 10 it give error : minumum reqiements...
so i decided to install it manually from the Inf file i tried and it gaved me this error 
: 
"the file you selected does not contain driver x64.."
so i want methode to force install it or just edit the inf file to make it could be install in windows 10

sorry for bad english

Comment: You don't;  That particular display driver is not compatible with Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

There are no drivers for windows 10 for Intel® HD Graphics for Previous Generation Intel® Processors which is your graphics on [intel's website](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/97497)

On windows 10 the drivers are automatically installed though, Try going to device manager and update the drivers or start windows update and it should install it.

You may try Intel driver assistant for automatic installation too, [Link here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html?iid=dc_iduu)

Also you might try to go device manager > display adapters and update > browse my computer and select the folder where your drivers are, Make sure you enable include sub folders.

Comment: Hi thanks for helping and the problem isnt find a driver i alredy have driver of 2012 installed automatically by microsoft but i want the 2013 version to run specefic program so is there  are way to force install the driver of windows 7 in windows 10

Comment: The driver in question is absolutely not compatible with Windows 10.

Comment: @ِAbdelmalekSmai No you can't force install windows 7 programs/drivers on windows 10, and even if you could it won't run as expected because it wasn't made for that environment